# Printf output for arrayList to table with proper indent

Tags: java, arraylist, format, printf, tabular

I am basically done with my assignment but there's a little formatting required in the output and I just don't understand how I can use `printf` to solve the issue. I never had to use it before.

I have the user input ids and pws, that get saved in an array list.

Output should look like this:

```
    Nr. Name                               Password (ROT13)
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1. Sally Hu                               nopNOP
 2. Bernd das Brot                         zrvaCnffjbeg
 3. John Doe                               klmTRURVZ
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

but looks like this for me:

```
 Nr. Name                                 Password (ROT13)
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1. Sally Hu                               nopNOP
 2. Bernd das Brot                             zrvaCnffjbeg
 3. John Doe                               klmTRURVZ
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Current code for the print:

```
  System.out.println("Nr. Name                       Passwort (ROT13)");


    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                    for(int i = 0; i < userList.size();i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println((userList.indexOf(userList.get(i))+1) +". " + userList.get(i).getmId() + "       " + rot13(userList.get(i).getmPw()));    
                    }
```

If someone could help me out real quick and maybe even explain some of the used `printf` functions used to solve this formatting problem? *(So I can properly format with `printf` in the future, instead of this hacky pseudo formatting using +"   "+ in my printlines that leads to problems like here)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just don't understand how I can use printf

Here is the method's signature, [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

```
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object... args)
```

Let's leave aside the returned value and **focus on the arguments**:

**format** is a string that specifies the formatting to be used and **args** is a list of the variables to be printed using that formatting.

Let's take an example.

Suppose you want to print a string in this specific format -> **"5 + 6 = 11"**.
But this is a specific instance of this formatted string, with these specific numbers, you instead want to put arbitary numbers and the result would be a string that shows the addition of those numbers.

The string format is this: a number, a space ' ', the plus sign '+', a number, a space, the equals sign '=', a space and finaly one more number. In order for `printf()` to understand this you need to supply it as a string in the first argument.

**This is that string**: `String format = "%d + %d = %d"`

`printf()` will know the format you want from that string above and it will replace every '%d' (%f for floats, %s for strings etc) with an integer variable. Those are the integers that you supple the **printf()** after.

Finally, at our specific example again, **"5 + 6 = 11"**.

```
int number1 = 5, number2 = 6;
String format = "%d + %d = %d";
//print the result formatted
System.out.printf(format,number1, number2, number1+number2);
```

You can change the values of number1 and number2, the result will be always their addition in the format that `String format` specifies.

Answer (score 0):

You can ident with "\t" in System.out.println:

```
System.out.println("test\ttest2");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 System.out.format("%d. %-15s %s%n", userList.indexOf(userList.get(i))+1, userList.get(i).getmId(), rot13(userList.get(i).getmPw()));
```

Comment: Thatworks perfectly. However im not quite sure If i understand it correctly. Could you explain it to me so I can use it to indent the line above saying Mr. Name  and Password(Rot13) the same way?

I tried 


System.out.printf("%-20s", "Nr. Name              Passwort (ROT13)");



and it works but that was more of a guess than really understanding

Comment: you can read about the formt method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and the format string is explaind [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). the format string I used sets the width of "Nr. Name" column to 15 characters and does right padding(- flag) so the values in the next column will be aligned. If you want to do the same for the header, you need two format specifiers as format and the width adjusted accordingly.